# Use Jupyter notebook/lab without root

Tags: 19.04, jupyter

​

I installed miniconda and I'm using the JupyterLab to explore datasets but I ran into an issue. Basically my miniconda install is in /root, it follows that everytime I want to launch a notebook it requires root access and I'm not willing to give it.

​

How do you I remedy that issue without destroying my install, can I just move miniconda to /home ?

​

Thanks,

P.S : I'm using Ubuntu 19.04 on a Lenovo thinkpad S2.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved with pyenv. it allows you to install multiple versions of python in a folder inside your home directory. So, no root is necessary.

pyenv is really straight forward. Basically check the pyenv wiki for " [Common build problems](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems)", there they list their dependencies.

Then go to the pyenv-installer page and copy this line:

```
 curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer/master/bin/pyenv-installer | bash
```

Afterwards put those lines at the end of your .bashrc:

```
export PATH="~/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

As you can see pyenv already comes with virtualenv installed as a plugin.

Finally use `pyenv install --list`  to view your install options and install a python version, 3.7.3 for instance, with :

```
pyenv install 3.7.3
```

On a given project folder you just run :

```
pyenv local 3.7.3
```

So the local folder and all the  subfolders will be set to that version of python. You can install another python version with pyenv and use different versions for different projects as required.